# Finding duplicate entries in many-to-many table

Tags: sql, many-to-many, one-to-many

We have two objects that ought to have a one to many relationship but for whatever reason the relationship is configured to be many to many.  So, we know this is not correct, but really the symptom is what needs to be fixed at the moment, which is the data problem.  How would you go about generating a list of all the records on one side that are associated with more than one record on the other side?  This list would be used to fix the data, even if we cannot yet fix the relationship.

The table contains the relationship between `x` and `y` which has two columns: `nManySide1` and `nManySide2`. `nManySide1` contains the primary key from the x table and `nManySide2` contains the primary key from the `y` table.

This is the query we came up with, but it does not turn up any results at all:

```
SELECT nManySide1, count(nManySide1),nManySide2, count(nManySide2) from dbo.X_Y
GROUP BY nManySide1, nManySide2
HAVING (COUNT(nManySide1) > 1 and COUNT(nManySide2) > 1)
```

Our interim solution is to dump the table to Excel, use conditional formatting to mark duplicates in Y and then remove/hide all rows that are not marked. But this is something we would like to be able to automate to let us know that the duplicates have been created and need to be fixed until we are able to recreate the relationship as one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if duplicates might appear in the table.  If so, then you would want:

```
SELECT nManySide1, count(distinct nManySide2) as cnt
from dbo.X_Y
GROUP BY nManySide1
HAVING count(distinct nManySide2) > 1;
```